# I have list of users data in table with view button aside if i click on view it will show details and deactivate button if i click user ac has to be

Tags: angular

Deactivate or activate for users already deactivated
View and status:

[image]

i am trying to do this but its not working

```
    activateOrDeactivateUser(Id, status) {
return this.http.put(environment.userApi + `/api/user/admin/user/${Id}/changeStatus`, { status });
```

}

```
    async activateORDeactivateUser(status: Boolean, name) {
    if (!status) {
        let confirmationByUser: any = await SwalAlert.confirmationAlert(`Are you sure you want to deactivate claimant  ${name}?`,
            '', `warning`, true, `Yes,Deactivate ${name}`, `No`)
        if (confirmationByUser.dismiss == 'cancel') { return }
    }

    this.loaderIcon = true;
    this.userService
        .activateOrDeactivateUser(this.userId, status)
        .subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
                // this.accountStatus=data;
                // console.log(this.userId);
                status ? SwalAlert.message('Done!', `Claimant name : ${name} activated `, 'success') : SwalAlert.message('Done!', `Claimant name : ${name} deactivated `, 'success');
                this.loaderIcon = false;
                console.log(this.loadClaimedUserList());
                this.modalService.dismissAll();
            }, error => {
                this.loaderIcon = false;
                Swal.fire('Oops...', 'Something went wrong!', 'error')
            })
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add more clarity to the question. From current, it looks like on button click, you are able to activate/deactivate a user from the backend but enable/disable on button is not working. Right? In that case, can you please also attach the HTML?

Comment: no the code is working fine until i filter api data removed null values and stored that array in another variable now i am trying to update api data value enable= true if deactivate user or false for activate after filtering api data this is not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.